# What is the relation to time of a thermodynamic cycle?

Tags: thermodynamics

A thermodynamic cycle consists of a fluid that exchanges heat and work with the environment. The fluid can be in multiple states, for example the temperature, pressure and volume can differ.
However, I an not sure what the connection is with time. I made two options:

A) at each moment in time, the fluid has one pressure and temperature, which is the same everywhere in the fluid. This changes through time, and there is a fixed time interval D such that for all t, the process is in the same state at time t and time t+D

B) the system does not change with time. However, the system is linked to many external reservoirs, and each has a different influence on the system. The net change in heat, for example, is $0$ at each time.

Which one of A and B is true? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theory of thermodynamic cycles assumes that the system is in equilibrium, i.e. uniform pressure, temperature and fields of other thermodynamic variables, so that they can be represented by a single value, the values you represent in $p$-$v$ diagram or $T$-$s$ diagram.

This is an approximation that holds for quasi-static transformations, that would imply infinite time for a cycle.

In real systems, thermodynamic variables are not uniform functions in space and this introduces some loss in the cycle efficiency, so that you can use classical thermodynamic cycles as the theoretical limit of the real ones.

Comment: What if the variations are not spatially uniform within the working fluid, but all variables vary periodically with the same frequency?  This certainly describes a cycle.

Comment: For sure. You get this if you start with the **equations of continuum mechanics**, using a (low order, if you know suitable base functions) approximation of the fields.

Comment: So the theory of thermodynamic cycles does not have to assume that the system is in equilibrium at all times, right?

Comment: Theory of thermodynamic cycles described in p-v diagram and other diagrams assumes that the system is in equilibrium. If you relax this assumption, thermodynamic equilibrium only holds locally for each point in space, and you need equations that describe fields in space

Comment: So in the simple case, it is option A?

Comment: the state of the system can change, as you describe these changes in the state diagram. Let's say that the characteristic time of the changes in the process (e.g. expansion of the combustion chamber, ...) are much longer than the characteristic time of thermodynamic equilibrium throughout the whole system (in classical thermodynamics), so that you can assume the system is always at equilibrium, despite its state changes